# Send logs from logstash to elasticsearch mismatch

Tags: linux, elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack, filebeat

I'm trying to ship logs from a server with filebeat to another server that hosts logstash and elasticsearch. Everything is latest and greatest (7.8.0). Problem is, I'm getting an error from logstash.

This is the error I get from logstash:

```
[2020-07-17T20:17:43,845][WARN ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][main][8ce40c8c6d7b7e92195bf01fa9d2c86d4bb1a87e7565d54444d45d82ebbd311f] Could not index event to Elasticsearch. {:status=>400, :action=>["index", {:_id=>nil, :_index=>"logstash", :routing=>nil, :_type=>"_doc"}, #<LogStash::Event:0x2594ed33>], :response=>{"index"=>{"_index"=>"logstash-2020.07.14-000001", "_type"=>"_doc", "_id"=>"0yZsXnMBpYpmFLee7cmh", "status"=>400, "error"=>{"type"=>"mapper_parsing_exception", "reason"=>"failed to parse field [host] of type [text] in document with id '0yZsXnMBpYpmFLee7cmh'. Preview of field's value: '{hostname=server150, os={kernel=3.10.0-1062.18.1.el7.x86_64, codename=Core, name=CentOS Linux, family=redhat, version=7 (Core), platform=centos}, containerized=false, ip=[*censoring public ip*], name=server150, id=3eec437c66d444a59ef5f075a429441d, mac=[*cencored*], architecture=x86_64}'", "caused_by"=>{"type"=>"illegal_state_exception", "reason"=>"Can't get text on a START_OBJECT at 1:111"}}}}}
```

I've followed suggestions from other posts of people having this issue and this is what my conf file for logstash looks like (tried fixing it with the mutate part):

```
input{
file{
path => "/var/log/commands.log"
}
beats{
port => 5044
}
}
filter {
mutate {
   rename => ["host", "server"]
   convert => {"server" => "string"} 
}
if [path] == "/var/log/commands.log" {
grok{
match => { "message" => "\[(%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:sys_timestamp})\]\s(?<field1>[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)\s(?<field2>[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)\:USER=(?<field3>[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)\sPWD=(?<field4>[0-9a-zA-Z_/-]+)\sPID=\[(?<field5>[0-9]+)\]\sCMD=\"(?<field6>.*)\"\sExit=\[(?<field7>[0-9]+)\]\sCONNECTION=(?<field8>.*)"
}
}
}
}
output{
elasticsearch { 
hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
index => "filteredindex"
}
}
```

But I still get the same error. I think it's just a mismatch in data and I can't get it to work. Does anyone know what's missing? Huge thanks ahead!

Comment: Can u check es logs?

Comment: Thanks for the respose, first line is the error log

Comment: Do you have both beats and file input?

Comment: Yeah, it takes the file locally. I just relized 30 minutes ago that that's why it wasn't working all along.

Comment: Hope that solved the problem. Any issues?

Comment: Thanks for the response!

Only issue is that the "if" statment is being ignored. Can't get it to say "if the name of the file is "commands.log" then do this grok stuff"

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue. Adding below thing solved my issue :

```
mutate {
  remove_field => [ "host" ]
}
```